# can't resolve all parameters angular because of constants provider

Tags: angular, typescript, dependency-injection, ionic3, angular-providers

i am getting a weird issue. i have a provider called **ConstantsProvider**. i am using it in several pages. 
i have created a new page and add constants as dependency after importing.

```
import {ConstantsProvider} from '../../../../providers/constants/constants';
```

and added as dependency in my page as

```
constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, private constants:ConstantsProvider)
```

this way i am doing in may be 20+ pages. when declaring in a page as above i am getting the error

> compiler.js:486 Uncaught Error: Can't resolve all parameters for
>   ASpaceBookingsPage: ([object Object], [object Object], ?).

after closing and running (`ionic serve`), **restarting**, **upgrading ionic** still getting the same issue. 
i have added it in app.module.ts and ConstantsProvider is having @Injectable decorator also.

if its any kind of syntax error it shouldnt work in all pages. if remove the dependency in this new page everything working fine. 
can someone help me out??
as it is a very big project i can share code or try reproducing outside.

Comment: please share the app.module , ConstantsProvider and the component where you are using it .

Comment: It's not finding your ConstantsProvider import. Check to make sure you have the directory imported correctly.

Comment: verified the import its path is correct. as i have mentioned created another provider it was working. the same provider working fine in other pages. not sure whats the issue

Answer (score 0):

This error means what it says:
`ConstantsProvider` has a constructor that is expecting parameters: `([object Object], [object Object], ?)`

So, when you add `ConstantsProvider` to the `providers:[]` in the `app.module.ts` (or `pages.module.ts` or whichever scope you add it), you need to provide those constructor arguments.

PS: Show your code if you want a specific answer/solution